# Extract data from single row and paste into new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in a worksheet in a single row (row 44) where the required data is in columns C,F,I,L and so on (i.e. data required every 3rd column starting from C).

This ends at column 'ET'

I need to extract this and paste it into another worksheet row where there are no column spaces.

I've looked around for solutions but its usually columns but this is data i need in one row.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this needs to be done even when the data in row 44 changes, you could do a macro. In a procedure, the following code could work as a guideline:

```
Public Sub copyover()
  Dim c As Long
  For c = 1 To 50
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, c).Value = _
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(44, c * 3).Value
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 looks spot on. I might qualify `Worksheets` with `ThisWorkbook.` but that's more style than necessity. Can `c` be `integer` or is there a chance of overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be a macro? Put this in the first destination cell on the other worksheet:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$44:$ET$44,1,3*(COLUMN(A1)-1)+1)
```

Then copy right

Comment: Good point @tigeravatar, user2762240 looks like you have a few options!